# Error al darle commit a un proyecto

Tags: git, github

Cuando trato de darle commit to master a un proyecto tengo el siguiente error:
[image: Error GitHub]

Estoy subiendo gran parte del proyecto, pero no se porque no me deja.

Comment: Por lo visto el contenido de esa carpeta era/es un repositorio de Git, por lo cual deberías llamarlo como submódulo o eliminar la carpeta .git que está en dicha carpeta.

Comment: Ya trate de eliminar la carpeta .git y nada

Comment: debes, ademas de borrar el repositorio interno, hacer un nuevo *commit* con los archivos que estaban en ese repositorio. Podrías usar la consola, es mejor que cualquier asistente, en el sentido que los errores son mas detallados.